# Mod rewrite not working at all (phtml/php)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting, php

Having some issues with .htaccess on my website. I'm trying to alter the suffix of the URLs for my website. URLs currently appear as:

```
www.example.com/about.phtml
```

I want to remove about.phtml and replace it with about so it looks like:

```
www.example.com/about
```

The examples I'm using are not what I need on the website so I would like code that I don't have to go through and specify which specific page to remove it from and rather do it all automatically.

I've tried using php instead of phtml with no luck. Here is the code I am using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.phtml -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.phtml
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

FYI: my host is JustHost and they allow me to edit my .htaccess but if anyone has heard of or had any problems with them please let me know, I spoke to their tech-support who couldn't help me any more than I can help myself.

Comment: So what happens when you go to `http://www.example.com/about`? Nothing happens?

Comment: Doesn't work already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.phtml [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.phtml [L]
```

Comment: Ok just used this now it works too! Thanks I'm not sure which to keep and why.

Comment: This answer is less robust than the accepted version above, the one above will check for a valid filename or directory before rewriting the url.  I would use that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can Check first your rewrite mode is on or not in apache\conf\httpd.conf file

check below code in httpd.conf file

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

if hash exist in above the line then remove hash and restart apache server

After then you can set below code in your cakephp httaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.phtml -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.phtml [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```